# Xcode 4 for Dummies: Why are Storyboard Settings not Being Applied When the App Runs?

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard, xcode4.3, ios5.1

**SOLUTION**

Make sure in the plist that the storyboard name is listed as the main storyboard file name.

---

I have a `Storyboard` with a `UINavigationViewController` that's connected to a `NavigationViewController` class and it's set as the `UIWindow rootViewController`. When the app runs (in the Simulator (5.1)) I get a blank black screen with the blue-ish navigation bar on the top.

The first problem is that in the storyboard, I set the navigation bar to black. I also set the status bar to translucent black. Neither styles are being honored when the app runs.

And the second problem is that the navigation controller's view is empty even though in the storyboard it has a relationship to a `UITableViewController`.

How can I fix both of these issues. I just started using Xcode again and had been using 4.0 before so the storyboards are throwing me off...

**UPDATE**

Here's the code as requested. Obviously I can't post the storyboard (can I?).

AppDelegate:

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"

@implementation AppDelegate

@synthesize window = _window;
@synthesize navigationController;

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

navigationController = [[NavigationViewController alloc] init];

    self.window.rootViewController = navigationController;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}

- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application {
}

- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application {
}

- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application {
}

- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {
}

- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application {
}

@end
```

NavigationViewController:

```
#import "NavigationViewController.h"

@interface NavigationViewController ()
@end

@implementation NavigationViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];

if (self) {
    }

    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (void)viewDidUnload {
    [super viewDidUnload];
}

 - (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

@end
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that you are setting as the root controller a completely blank root controller, not the one from the story board. What you want to do is to delete that part of the code, and simply on the storyboard click the thing that says "is initial view controller"

When using storyboards you usually dont have to modify the appdelegate, because xcode sets which is the initial view that will appear and all of that based solely on how you set the storyboard. You can check this in the plist where it says which storyboard will be used as the main one.

If you want to load your navigation controller like that then you can do something like that you would have to get the viewcontroller from the storyboard itself and present it.

> instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier

but there is no need for that when using storyboards as it automatically loads whichever is set as the initial one (which can be seen as the viewcontroller with the arrow pointing at it)

Your app delegate method should look like this

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: And that's how I've understood storyboards to work, but if I comment out the assignment in the AppDelegate I simply get a blank screen. The navigation controller has been marked as *Is Initial View Controller* since the beginning of the project, yet nothing shows up. Without the assignment in the AppDelegate I get a completely blank screen. At least with the assignment I get a navigation bar...

Comment: yes you get one because you are programatically creating one to show but this one has nothing to do with the story board one. Have you changed anything else from the configuration? plist or project settings? Add a button or image to the first view of the navigation controller to see if you see something

Comment: Actually to test if you have, simply add a normal View COntroller with 1 button, then move the arrow to this one and see if you see that one. if you do it means you are setting your navigation vc incorrectly

Comment: Tried the test you suggested and I still get a blank black screen. I also get this error: "Application windows are expected to have a root view controller at the end of application launch" which is why I was trying to assign the controller in the delegate.

Comment: NEVER MIND! I got it. I just remembered this little 2 second part of a YouTube video where the maker had set the storyboard name in the plist. Since I started with an empty project and manually added the storyboard that's why it was missing. Anyway, you're right about the other stuff though so I'll pick your answer.

Comment: you must have modified something in your project. Try a fresh project and see what did you change.